# What happens when glUniform4f is called to set a float3 variable?

Tags: opengl

Will OpenGL automatically truncate it or is this an error?

I have a piece of nasty OpenGL code that seems to be setting an array of float4x3 in the program by using glUniform4fv with a big array that has float4 values in it (i.e. 4 floats per row instead of 3), and it seems to work. That is OpenGL only copies 3 values to each row of the matrix and skips the 4th one. Is it OK to assume this will always work?

Comment: OpenGL does not have `float4`, `float3`, or `float4x3` types. Are you talking about `vec4`, `vec3`, and `mat4x3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GLSL specification is quite clear on this: the size and type for `glUniform*` calls must *exactly* match the size and type declared in the shader (except for samplers and booleans). So if you call `glUniform4fv`, you must be setting either a single variable of type `vec4` or an array of `count` entries in an array variable of type `vec4`.